How do I save each worksheet in a workbook as a separate file?
This code works great except that is saves every worksheet in the workbook.  I need it to save each worksheet in the workbook as a separate file.  I need it to save each tab separately giving the new file the same name as the Worksheet.  I understand that it would involve copying or moving each tab and then saving but I don't know how to do that.  Can my current code be edited to accomplish what I want?
Sub Save_Tabs()


     Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
     Dim SaveToDirectory As String
     Dim filename As String

     Dim CurrentWorkbook As String
     Dim CurrentFormat As Long

     CurrentWorkbook = ThisWorkbook.FullName
     CurrentFormat = ThisWorkbook.FileFormat

      SaveToDirectory = "E:\NYCHHC\CSOD\Reports\completion reports\"

     For Each ws In Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
                 Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                 ws.SaveAs SaveToDirectory & ws.Name ' FileFormat:=xlNormal, CreateBackup:=False

     Next
End Sub

Thanks for your help


Your code is close to finish. Copy method of worksheet object will create a new workbook.
The current code might overwrite existing files in the destination directory. You may need extra code lines to check it.

Microsoft documentation:

Worksheet.Copy method (Excel)

    For Each ws In Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        ws.Copy
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs SaveToDirectory & ws.Name & ".xlsx", FileFormat:=xlNormal, CreateBackup:=False
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        ActiveWorkbook.Close False
    Next


This works for one sheet.  When it goes to the next sheet, it breaks.  Message is "we can't copy this sheet.

A screenshot of error popup windows is helpful. Please try to create a new workbook and test the code to export its worksheets.

first sheet was a graph.  I deleted that sheet and got it to work

Export Sheets As Workbooks
The following basic code will fail,

if a workbook with the same name is open,
if a sheet name is an invalid folder name,
if a sheet is not visible,...

Sub ExportSheetsAsWorkbooks()

    Const DST_FOLDER_PATH As String = _
        "E:\NYCHHC\CSOD\Reports\completion reports\"

    Dim swb As Workbook: Set swb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim ssh As Object

    For Each ssh In swb.Sheets
        ssh.Copy
        With Workbooks(Workbooks.Count)
            ' To overwrite an existing file, to remove sheet code,
            ' to save if incompatible (e.g. when more than 65536 rows
            ' while saving to '.xls'),... without confirmation:
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                .SaveAs DST_FOLDER_PATH & ssh.Name ' as '.xlsx' file
                ' Or:
                '.SaveAs DST_FOLDER_PATH & ssh.Name & ".xls", xlWorkbookNormal
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
            .Close SaveChanges:=False
        End With
    Next ssh

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    MsgBox "Sheets exported as single workbooks.", vbInformation

End Sub


thanks for the code.  The workbook that has the code and the workbook that has all the tabs are two different workbooks.   So the line that has defines swb is referring to the wrong workbook.  There must be a way to define swb as the current workbook, right?

So I set swb to ActiveWorkbook and it copied the first tab to a separate file. But on the Next ssh I got a this message: "We couldn't copy this Sheet".  Any idea why that would be?

What is the full error message (number and description)? What is the name of the sheet?

The first worksheet was a graph.  I deleted that and it works now
